# Software to determine cluster speed

Tags: c++, c

I want to compare 2 clusters for single core performance. One cluster is based on Mac OS X and the other one is a centOS cluster.

Is there a C/C++ code that I can compile on each and run and see how fast it runs on both for comparison?

Comment: What operating system and cluster abstraction framework are you using?

Comment: If you pick a random program and run it on both, how will you know that gives you any useful data regarding the performance you need?

Comment: What you are looking for is called a Cluster Benchmark - there are several available but as with any benchmark a lot will depend on the planned usage of the cluster(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of benchmark only can give you an approximation because whatever you compile might not be comparable because the same code might get more optimized on the one cluster than on the other. Choosing optimal and non-optimal compiler settings might already make a big difference.

When I understand you correctly you are only looking for single core performance. In that scenario it should not matter if you are using a cluster or not.

Either [look up](https://www.spec.org/cgi-bin/osgresults?conf=cpu2006;op=form) the specint value for the different cpus you are using. Or simply run `7z` in benchmark mode, limited to one thread: `7z b -mmt1`.
All this can give you an *idea* of the speed, but to get *real* figures you need to run a test that fits the usage scenario of your cluster.